# Resources for solving mixed left and right matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, linear-solver, reference-request

I'm looking to solve a matrix equation and not sure where to start looking for resources.
The equation is
$$AX + XB = C\,,$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.
(Alternatively $AX + XA = C$ with $n=m$ would be useful.)

I can see that I could change it into a system
$$A'\mathbf{x}' = \mathbf{b}'\,,$$
with $A' \in \mathbb{R}^{nm\times nm}$, ${\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{nm}}$, ${\mathbf{b}\in \mathbb{R}^{nm}}$, but was wondering if there were any shortcuts I could take.

Comment: Whilst we're here, is there a name for problems which include $EXD$ terms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), although normally the matrices would all be square. Even for rectangular matrices, the [Bartels-Stewart method](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/361573.361582) applies (also [*A Hessenberg-Schur Method for the Problem $AX+XB=C$*, Golub, Nash, Van Loan](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/Hessenberg.Schur.Method.pdf)).

The idea is to use the Schur decompositions
$$ A = URU^\top, \qquad B^\top = VSV^\top, $$
so that $AX+XB=C$ is transformed into
$$ RY+YS^\top = F, \qquad Y = U^\top XV, F = U^\top CV. $$

Since $R$ is upper-triangular and $S^\top$ lower-triangular, this can be used to solve the system directly. If $Y = [y_1, \ldots, y_m]$ are the columns of $Y$, and $f_k$ are the columns of $F$, then the equation for $y_k$ depends only on $y_{k+1},\ldots,y_m$, and can be solved with back-substitution:
$$ (R+s_{kk}I)y_k = f_k - \sum_{j>k} s_{kj}y_j. $$
When using the real Schur decomposition, this would sometimes be a coupled linear equation in $y_k, y_{k+1}$ instead.

This also shows it doesn't matter if $m\neq n$. To convert to the usual Sylvester equation with $m=n$ one could also just pad the matrices with zeros to obtain an equivalent problem.